# non-math arrow graphics in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

how would one create a graphical arrangement somewhat like  [this](https://eiserneketten.de/arrows.png) in pdflatex/beamer?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). People here are usually reluctant to answer question that just post an image of the desired result and expect others to draw it.  Please show what you have tried and perhaps post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  To get you started, I would recommend that you read up on [Ti*k*Z](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).  There are many tutorials on this site and on the internet more generally.

Comment: In addition to @JP-Ellis answer you could look at: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/ or http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/arrows/ or http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/      Ti*k*Z generally works fine with beamer due to having the same author. The Ti*k*Z manual mentioned also has tutorials in it, and a whole chapter each on *Arrows* (Ch. 16) and *Nodes and Edges* (Ch. 17), which should be the most helpful...

Answer (score 2):

Just to get you started, here's a very simple implementation in Ti*k*Z.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to customize it and make it suit your needs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={
      text width=5em, 
      align=center,
      fill=blue!30,
      draw=blue!30,
    },
  ]
  \node (cl) {Company Loyalty};
  \node [right=2cm of cl] (tl) {Team Loyalty};
  \draw[-stealth, blue!40, line width=1em] (cl) -- (tl);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (a bit more fancy?):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings,shadows,shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1mm,
  box/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners,
        text width=17mm, align=center, inner sep=3mm, minimum height=12mm,
        top color=blue!25, bottom color=blue!50,
        drop shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, shadow yshift=-0.5pt},
            },
Arrow/.style = {single arrow, minimum height=12mm, minimum width=12mm, 
        single arrow head extend=2mm, fill=gray!30!blue!10,
        drop shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, shadow yshift=-0.5pt},
        node contents={}
            },
  ]
\node (n1) [box]                {Company Loyalty};
\node (n2) [Arrow,right=of n1];
\node (n1) [box,right=of n2]    {Team Loyalty};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```